# BigCouch error: "couldn't connect to host" when joinning a node

Tags: couchdb, cluster-computing, bigcouch

I try to setup 2 nodes with BigCouch. I  set FQDN on /etc/hostname on 2 machines (example: may2.test.com). I also edited /opt/bigcouch/etc/vm.args:

- -name bigcouch@may2.test.com
- -setcookie monster (as default)

Then I try:

- curl localhost:5984 ->
  {"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.1.1","bigcouch":"0.4.2"}
- curl localhost:5986 -> {"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.1.1"}
- curl may2.test.com:5984 ->
  {"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.1.1","bigcouch":"0.4.2"}
- curl may2.test.com:5986 -> **curl: (7) couldn't connect to host**

Anyone can give me some ideas to fix it & make BigCouch work perfectly? Thank you alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I aslo fixed this error:

- Remove CouchDB. BigCouch ‘s enough.
- because I install BigCouch on localhost, my query must like:

> ```
> curl -X PUT http://localhost:5986/nodes/bigcouch@slave3.test.com -d {}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration file `/opt/bigcouch/etc/default.ini`

in the section `[httpd]` set `bind_address = 0.0.0.0` and then `sudo sv restart bigcouch`